# execute python script in html

Tags: php, python, html

I have two files in my "py" file in the "www" in wamp (local server)
the first file is python and the code is:

```
print("Hello")
print("Jane")
print("doe")
```

the script in php:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>php with py</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<?php

$output = array();
exec("py C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.py", $output);
var_dump( $output);
?>

</body>

</html>
```

it doesn't work, I get this error:

```
C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.php:19:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

I have checked in cmd that line:

```
py C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.py
```

and it works!

what is wrong?

Comment: Is your safe_mode on?

Comment: @Carlos Alexandre how do I check?

Comment: @napuzba answered well, check there first.

Comment: Check with phpinfo if the safe mode is active

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: removed safe mode and still the same.

Comment: exec("full-path-to-python C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.py", $output);

Comment: tried this and didn't work:  exec("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.py", $output);

Comment: Are you already tried with http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use full path to python.

```
exec('"full-path-to-python" "C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.py"', $output);
```

Comment: Try to enclose with the paths with ".

Comment: didn't understand.. I tried this: exec("<C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python> C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.py", $output);

Comment: First, remove the <> . Also, verify that you python is also x64 (using python -v)

Answer (score 1):

run python --help in the command line, you can find the python path in the output

```
python --help
```

> usage:
>   C:\Users\Roofe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
>   [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ... Options and
>   arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
>   -b     : issue warnings about str(bytes_instance), str(bytearray_instance)

then set the python path in you php exec like,

```
exec("C:\Users\Roofe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe C:\wamp64\www\py\py_8.py", $output);
```

Comment: got this: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User>PS C:\Users\Roofe> python --help
'PS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: in the cmd window, run `python --help`, and first you have python installed.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User>python --help
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
and I have python!

Comment: check where your python is installed, and check the environment path